# How to store a field value in nested dictionary using python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, elasticsearch

Here is my index(**sub_application**), I need to pass values to the keys **(id, name)** in **approved_by** object. I tried in different ways nothing workout

```
{
  "settings": {
  },
  "mappings": {
    "sub_application": {
      "properties": {
        "archived_at": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "approved_by": {
           "properties": {
              "name": {
                 "type": "text"
               },
              "id": {
                "type": "text"
               }
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Attempt1:**

```
     for info in sub_application_obj['hits']['hits']:
                print(info)
                item = info['_source']
                current_employer = item['approved_by']
                client.update(index='sub_application',
                  doc_type='sub_application',
                  body={'doc': { 
                         current_employer['name']: approved_user,
                         current_employer['id']: approved_userid
                             }},
                    id=info['_id'])
```

**Attempt2:**

```
    client.update(index='sub_application',
                  doc_type='sub_application',
                  body={'doc': { 
                         ['approved_by']['name']: approved_user,
                         ['approved_by']['id']: approved_userid 
                             }},
                    id=info['_id'])
```

**Attemp3:**

```
   client.update(index='sub_application',
              doc_type='sub_application',
              body={'doc': { 
                     ['approved_by.name']: approved_user,
                     ['approved_by.id']: approved_userid 
                         }},
                id=info['_id'])
```

I need to pass **approved_user** and **approved_userid** to the keys **name, id**  in **approved_by object**. I tried but didn't get it,please help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Elastic a nested field is an array of object. Here you just need to pass data to a sub object.

```py
client.update(index='sub_application',
              doc_type='sub_application',
              body={
                 'doc': { 
                    'approved_by': {'name': approved_user, 'id': approved_userid}
                 }
              },
              id=info['_id'])
```

and for a nested object :

```py
client.update(index='sub_application',
              doc_type='sub_application',
              body={
                 'doc': { 
                    'approved_by': [{'name': approved_user, 'id': approved_userid}]
                 }
              },
              id=info['_id'])
```

You can have more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408080/elasticsearch-query-sub-objects).